# text format color in description embed

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make the description embed look the same:

````
```fix
text here```
````

but he gives this error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: "This is a test: `" is not a function

he gives this error only when I put the three ```, when I put only one he send normal

````
const reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
            user.send({embed: {
                color: "#d96d21", 
                title: "warning",
                description: `This is a test:\n\```fix\n${reason}\``` \n end`,
            }})
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape all three backticks:

```js
const reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
user.send({embed: {
    color: "#d96d21", 
    title: "warning",
    description: `This is a test:\n\`\`\`fix\n${reason}\`\`\` \n end`,
}})
```